# Find ordinal for the column in Primary Key using SMO

Tags: smo

I wanted to find out if there is a method or property exposed by SQL SMO classes that can tell me the Ordinal for the column in a primary key.

I know how to find it using SQL Query but I wanted to avoid executing query if information is readily available in SMO objects.

Comment: I see that IndexedColumnCollection already returns IndexedColumn in order of their ordinal. I am good for now.